# When using OleDBDataReader to select a memo field from an Access database it only returns part of the string. How can I get the whole string?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledbdatareader

This is my code:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(
   "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\\Offline.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT B.* FROM BlankFormSubmissions B, Actions A WHERE A.FormName = 'FindingNemo' AND B.ProcessName = A.ProcessName AND B.ActionName = A.ActionName AND B.ID = 12 OR B.ID = 13 OR B.ID = 14 ORDER BY B.ID";
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    string xml = (string)reader["XML"];
    // ... do something with xml
}
```

The column, "XML", is an Access Database table column, of type memo.

The value of xml always contains only the first characters of the XML.  I'm guessing it's the first 256 characters.  Obviously, I need all of the characters in the string.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Just a guess - have you tried crafting the select statement so the XML column is last?  In some of the older database systems, the large columns had to be last in the select list.

Comment: Thanks.  I gave that a try, but unfortunately still get the same problem :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem could be the memo field itself;

Memo fields can't be used in Aggregate Arguments ( like Max, Var, Sum etc. )
If used in 'Group By' totals in a query only the first 255 characters are returned.
'Having' and 'Where' clauses in Group Aggregate functions also return only the first 255 chars
However, using 'First' or 'Last' arguments return the full length of the string.

Is this the entire SQL statement?

Comment: The poster isn't doing aggregation... "SELECT * FROM BlankFormSubmissions"

Comment: Although you don't appear to be using aggregates, it might be worth trying to change to a text field and checking it.

Comment: Sorry guys... I thought my SQL statement would have nothing to do with the problem, so I summarized it to make my code easier to read.  I actually found that when I use the simpler SQL, it does work, so Johnny may actually be right.

Comment: I've edited my code above and put in the actual SQL statement that's causing the problem.

Comment: @Johnny DropTables - I can't revoke my downvote unless you edit the question.  Can you please do that do I can upvote?

Comment: The "DISTINCT" was causing the problem.  I voted the answer up one... so I hope that cancels out the down vote... not too sure how these points work.

Comment: You seriously have to ask yourself if you have a schema error if you think you need to include a memo field in a SELECT DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

this way;)

```
 OleDbCommand sqlcmdCommand1 = new OleDbCommand("select stmt", sqlconConnection);
        sqlcmdCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        try
        {
            sqlconConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader sdaResult = sqlcmdCommand1.ExecuteReader();
            myclass a = new myclass();
            while (sdaResult.Read())
            {

               a.i = sdaResult.GetString(2);
               or 
               int i = sdaResult.GetString(2)); 
              // 2 is the index of your column, in general start from 0;'
            }
```

if this do not work , i mean if you the value of my_memo_value is null then:
create a class in which you get and set value of string and int.
and then use it here
Like

```
Myclass {
Public int i{get;set}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same problem :(

Comment: put a break point and see if your query parameter has the same value as you passed to it.